# PermissionHandler: Checking a permanently denied permission returns false unless requesting the permission is done first

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-permissions

This question is about [permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package.

There are 2 methods in the library to check for a permission's status, for example in case of the microphone we can call:

- `PermissionStatus status1 = await Permission.microphone.status //call 1`
- `PermissionStatus status2 = await Permission.microphone.request() //call 2`

suppose a user presses the 'dont ask again' when he is prompted to grant the permission.
Now  If:

- we make **call 1** to get the permission status, we should expect to get `PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied` but the result is `PermissionStatus.denied`
- we make **call 2** to get the permission status, we expect to get `PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied` and without the dialouge appearing again to the user, and this is exactly what happens

So **call 2** works as intended but **call 1** works as if there are only 2 states for a permission that can be returned from this call: granted or denied. But then how can we get the real status of the permission (for example it may be `deniedPermanently`) without calling `request()` in this case? Is this a bug or is this the intended behaviour? Sometimes I need to just check the status of the permission but I don't want to open a permission dialouge to the user, how to do that?

### I will explain my use-case breifly:

I call the `Permission.microphone.request()` first time and then update my widget's state, then if the app (in android: activity) is paused, in the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method which comes from the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin, I do check if the permission was revoked or permanently denied using `Permission.microphone.status`, but the problem is that this method is returning a `denied` status even when the permission is `permanentlyDenied`, and the correct return value which is `permanentlyDenied` is only returned if I call `Permission.microphone.request()`

code demo:

```
      PermissionStatus result = await Permission.microphone.request();//this returns permanentlyDenied without opening the dialouge => ok
      PermissionStatus result = await Permission.microphone.status;//this returns denied even if the status was permanently denied without opening the dialouge => NOT OK
```

Comment: did you try using `shouldShowRequestRationale`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you explain more please?

Comment: `shouldShowRequestRationale` used to check if user is request for the 1st time. Then we have to store on memory. On next call, if you permanentlyDenied, dialog won't show. Then we will show our custom dialog. Should i add the code?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I will edit the question to show my use-case and then if you need add code please

Comment: oh and yes `deniedPermanently` doesn't show up on Android.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh that's  not true, it shows up, but not from the call to `Permission.microphone.status`, but rather from the call to `Permission.microphone.request()`, and my problem is that I don't want to call the latter but I want to call the first.

Comment: Maybe but I tried on Storage permission, it was providing me denied, then I handled using `Sharedpreferance` and `shouldShowRequestRationale`.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I updated the question with code to show my problem exactly, please have a look and add some code with explanation if you need, regards

Comment: @Haidar Facing the same issue create a issue !
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/799

Comment: @AnkitParmar you can benifit from the discussion here https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/647

Answer (score 0):

This is a [limitation](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/647#issuecomment-895730119) with the Android SDK where it only returns denied regardless if the user **denied** or **permanently denied** the permission. As a workaround, you can fetch the current status with `Permission.microphone.status;`. If the user selected the option to be "never asked again", you can store their [preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), and check the user preference before calling `Permission.microphone.request()`